# Microsoft Excel Formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am creating an Evaluation Form using Excel. There are 9 rows (evaluation criteria) and each has 5 columns (ratings: 5, 4, 3, 2, 1). The evaluator will place an "X" in the appropriate column for each row.  I need to "scan" the columns in each row and place the appropriate number in the sum field for that row.  If there is an "X" is the N/A column the sum column is left blank for that row.

[image: Evaluation Form]

Answer (score 3):

Use the MATCH function.  Put this in I14:

```
=IFERROR(6-MATCH("X",C14:G14,0),"")
```

And copy down.

Comment: Thank you!  My use of functions is limited.  Never even thought about MATCH!

Comment: @Steve if your problem is solved, please click the green checkmark next to the answer that solved the problem.